# Data not inserting in Sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an application which requires use of an SQLite database. I have implemented fetching the data, but I am facing problems when I try to insert data. The problem that I am having is that the new data I enter is not stored, i.e nothing is new is being entered into the database.

This is my insert code, `myDataBase` is an instance of SQLiteDatabase.

```
public void insertTitle(String Recipe)  
{  
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();  
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_NAME,value);  
    myDataBase.insert(ZRECIPE, null, initialValues);  
 }
```

Comment: What is the return value from `insert()`: -1 (error), or a valid row ID?

Answer (score 5):

Try it this way. You need first start transaction, then mark it as successful and end.

```
   try {  
       myDataBase.beginTransaction();
       myDataBase.insert(ZRECIPE, null, initialValues);
       myDataBase.setTransactionSuccessful();
       } 
   finally {
       myDataBase.endTransaction();
       }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to do an explicit transaction in order to get it to commit? Doesn't SQLite use autocommit mode by default?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to commit the transaction.

Comment: Hi, but how to commit the transcaction..?

Comment: Not sure but I guess that `setTransactionSuccessful()` actually is the commit.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code this may help you

```
public void insertTitle(String Recipe)  
{  
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();  
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_NAME,Recipe);  
    myDataBase.insert(ZRECIPE, null, initialValues);  
 }
```