# How to increment field in sqlite android database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, increment

I want to increment a column in a sqlite android database. Im doing like this:

```
public void atualiza(String word){
   this.db.rawQuery("UPDATE words SET count = count + 1 WHERE word= ? ", new String[] {word});     
}
```

And I call this method on another class like this:

```
this.dh.atualiza(word);
```

But when i pull the database from the emulator and check with the SQLite Database Browser, the field is not incremented. Why?

Comment: how about if you do a select from within your code (select count from words where word=?), does it return the correct value? (are you definitely pulling the right database?)

Comment: I think `rawQuery` returns an error code. Can you check what it is? Also, updates should be made with execSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really use `execSQL` for a query that does not return a table: [Increase the value of a record in android/sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427516/increase-the-value-of-a-record-in-android-sqlite-database/3432777#3432777)

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a transaction on the database [Data not inserting in Sqlite database in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483123/data-not-inserting-in-sqlite-database-in-android/3486373#3486373)

Comment: I should point out that when transactions are not specified, SQLite makes its own.

Comment: Hmm.. do you know good android docs about that feature? I'd highly appreciate a link.

Comment: It's a feature of SQLite, not so much as Android, but here is the official doc: http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html : "No changes can be made to the database except within a transaction. Any command that changes the database (basically, any SQL command other than SELECT) will automatically start a transaction if one is not already in effect. Automatically started transactions are committed when the last query finishes."

Comment: Its ok. The problem was change from rawQuery to execSQL.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: But how do you get the number of affected rows then?