# Java: line executes before previous line finishes running?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

First sorry for my bad English so I'll just ask my question.

I wrote my source

```
db.execSQL(String.format("DELETE FROM 'myTable' WHERE id=%d", i));
db.execSQL(String.format("UPDATE 'myTable' SET id=%d WHERE id=%d", i, i+1);
refreshList();
```

`refreshList()` gets myTable table's rows and set ListAdapter to a ListView with `new ArrayList<String>`.

but when it goes to refreshList function, it shows a previous database contents.

What seems to be the problem?

**EDIT**

This is the whole code what I written.

```
SQLiteDatabase db;

db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();

db.execSQL(String.format("DELETE FROM '_CTGLIST' WHERE id=%d", i));
db.execSQL(String.format("UPDATE '_CTGLIST' SET id=%d WHERE id=%d", i, i+1));

db.close();

refreshList();
```

and

```
private void refreshList() {
    ArrayList<String> mCategoryList = new ArrayList<String>;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor;

    db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cuCategory = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM '_CTGLIST' ORDER BY id ASC;", null);
    while (cuCategory.moveToNext()) {
        mCategoryList.add(cuCategory.getString(0));
    }
    db.close();
    //and set list adapter here.
    //i won't write this part of code in here.
}
```

Comment: First, why are you rewriting row IDs? That's a serious code smell. Additionally, without at least the `refreshList()` method, and probably also the code for opening the database connection, it's impossible to tell what's happening.

Comment: Additionally, *don't* build dynamic SQL like this. Use parameterized SQL, always. While there isn't a risk of SQL injection in this case, it's worth getting into good habits.

Comment: Can you show us the complete code - how are you handling exceptions in this block? Also, what are you expecting to happen? If I=1234, the you delete this record and then try to set its id to 12345. This should update zero rows as row 1234 has been deleted.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment re Also, what... I misread the question and I can't edit the comment.

Comment: @chrylis I'm first on database related coding so I really don't know what the good code is.

Comment: @JonSkeet It don't need to protect from SQL Injection because only me will use this app hehe ;)

Comment: OK, i updated this post with the whole code so lease check it

Comment: @AlfredWoo: As I say, it's a good habit to get into. Get into it *right away*, rather than excusing the bad code just because you're new to it. The sooner you get into good habits, the easier it'll be.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok then I will. Thank you for your advise!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your query is executed first and not commited and then you are using a new connection in the refreshList method, so it will give you a result for the data that is commited and not the ones that are yet to be commited.

Comment: This answer only makes sense refreshList uses a *different* connection (within the same connection/transaction, COMMIT means nothing)

Comment: Can you give more details on the refreshList() method as from the post it is not clear whether there is a different connection or it is using the same connection. Hence the specultion.

Comment: So there is a strong reason to think that the refreshList is using a new connection, which would be outside of your transaction. TO confirm, would it be possible to commit your transaction before calling refreshList

Comment: I updated my thread with the source codes so please check about it.

Comment: @Alfred Woo: Try begining and closing the transaction and marking the transction as successful before closing the connection. [Refer this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483123/data-not-inserting-in-sqlite-database-in-android)

Comment: @ganaraj what that means? could you give me some detail ways to do that?