# Inserting data into db from wakeful intent service in Android

Tags: android, database, google-cloud-messaging, background-service

Need some help in using databases in Android.

I am trying to insert data into a db provided by `MoEngage` from `doWakefulWork()` inside `WakefulIntentService`.

Here's my function to insert data into db :

```
private void addToDb(Bundle extras) {
    String msgDetails = "my string";
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    if (null != msgDetails) {
        values.put("msg", msgDetails);
    }

    Uri newRecord = App.context.getContentResolver().insert(MoEDataContract.MessageEntity.getContentUri(App.context),
            values);
    App.context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(newRecord, (ContentObserver) null);

    if (MoEHelperUtils.isDebugEnabled()) {
        if (null != newRecord) {
            Log.d(MoEHelper.TAG, "PushMessagingListener: added new record with entry: " + newRecord);
        } else {
            Log.d(MoEHelper.TAG, "PushMessagingListener: FAILED to add new record with entry: ");
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I open the app and try to query the database, the cursor returns 0 count.

If I try to query right after adding values inside `doWakefulWork()` only, the cursor shows the value in database.

```
Cursor cursor = MoEController.getAllMessages(App.context);
```

Am I missing somethings here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3486373/1349601

It looks like you should create a transaction and mark it as successful.

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples on how to insert a data on Android by ContentValue:

- [Inserting data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Permissions) - To insert data into a provider, you call the ContentResolver.insert() method. This method inserts a new row into the provider and returns a content URI for that row.
- [BooksProvider.java](https://github.com/davidllorca/Provider/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/davidllorca/provider/BooksProvider.java)
- [OwnContentProviderActivity.java](https://github.com/davidllorca/Provider/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/davidllorca/provider/OwnContentProviderActivity.java)

The Context can be either null or not. I found this possibility because the Context is null in the sample code about inserting data in [Github](https://github.com/davidllorca/Provider/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/davidllorca/provider/BooksProvider.java). So, I have assumed that maybe the ‘App’ is using Singleton pattern.

You may check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere).

> This won't work if your SQLiteOpenHelper is used by a Content Provider, because the Content Provider's onCreate() is called before the Application's onCreate().